# Error with c insertion sort

Tags: c, insertion-sort

I am making a c insertion sort and it works fine except that after the sort the first number is always a weird negative number and the program errors out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void insertionSort(int list[], int last){
     int hold;
     int walker;
     int current;
     int count;

     count = 0;
     for (current = 1; current <= last; current++){
         hold = list[current];
         for (walker = current - 1; 
             walker >= 0 && hold < list[walker]; walker--){
                    list[walker + 1] = list[walker];
             }
         list [walker + 1] = hold;
         count++;
     }
     printf("\n\nHow many passes to sort?\n%d\n\n", count);
     return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int numbers[100];
  int i;

  srand(time(NULL));
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      numbers[i] = rand() % 100;
  }
  printf("Unsorted Numbers\n-------- -------\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      printf("%d,", numbers[i]);
  }
  insertionSort(numbers, 100);
  printf("\nSorted Numbers\n-------- -------\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      printf("%d,", numbers[i]);
  }
  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going OVER the array size within the loop. When current = last, list[last] is list[100], the 101th element of the array... this is also not good.

Edit. I just tested this out and it worked for me. Only thing i changed was the <= in the outer loop to n <

```
void insertionSort(int list[], int last){
 int hold;
 int walker;
 int current;
 int count;

 count = 0;
 for (current = 1; current < last; current++){
     hold = list[current];
     for (walker = current - 1; 
         walker >= 0 && hold < list[walker]; walker--){
                list[walker + 1] = list[walker];
         }
     list [walker + 1] = hold;
     count++;
 }
 printf("\n\nHow many passes to sort?\n%d\n\n", count);
 return;
}
```

Comment: still does it after I change it

Comment: did you go through the rest of your sort? For instance, walker = current - 1; will be -1 when current is 0, and your inner loop will never be accessed.

Comment: no matter what I seem to change it says stack around the variable 'numbers' is corrupted

Comment: it appears that the highest number is always the corrupted one. It spits out -858993460

Comment: you know what... now that I think about it, your outer loop should be for(current=1; current<last; current++). Also, i think that the line before count++ right before the second loops end should be list [walker] = hold;. haven't tested it out though.

Comment: no, list[walker+1] = hold is fine. sorry, im all over the place.

Comment: it still seems to spit out that weird wrong number for the largest number sorted. It worked when I created it about a year ago using visual studio 2008. I am now using 2010 could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: nope, vs 2010 should work the same. let me update my answer to what i think it should be... tell me if you have the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare an array like

```
int numbers[100]
```

**numbers[99]** is the last element. In your sort function you are accessing **numbers[100]** as well.

Comment: It gives me runtime stack error 2 stack around variable numbers was corrupted